# What languages are mostly in demand these days?

Tags: programming-languages

I want to know which programming languages are mostly in demand in this era of software development and web development. I have learned c++, java, vb.net , asp.net c#, php, html, css, javascript, coldfusion. I want to know which other languages are important to know and is widely used in the job market and have great future scope. I would appreciate your guys input into this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a frequently updated list based on search engine activity regarding the various languages:

http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html

Comment: TIOBE is crap.  http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2008/01/you_can_use_statistics_to_prov.html

Comment: @Andy Lester:  It's just a data point and should be treated as such.  I personally don't think search engine activity correlates as closely with market penetration as it does with language difficulty.

Comment: But it's a meaningless data point.  You can draw no meaningful conclusions from having more hits on "java programming" than "fortran programming."

Answer (score 1):

What I see a lot of lately in job postings are experience in python, ruby on rails, and sql.  It really depends on the field you are in and what your primary focus is.  What job market in particular are you looking at?  For example, in the scientific community, expertise in python, R, and sql are valued.  In web design/programming, definitely CSS3, ruby on rails, and jquery for html5 development.  Another big item right now is iPhone development, specifically Objective-C 2.0 and iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously any managed code (Java, .NET ...) makes projects much economic than script-based or non-managed ones. Among them I recommend .NET (C#, VB or F#) because of integration with other technologies of the same company. Software development is about time. Any platform, tools, languages which do the job faster are preferred and among them Microsoft visual studio and .NET framework platform (ASP.NET for web applications) using popular C# language is the market choice at the moment. Just take a look at questions on *StackOverFlow.com* and judge yourself.

Comment: "Obviously any managed code (Java, .NET ...) makes projects much economic than script-based or non-managed ones."  That's not obvious at all.  How do you figure "managed code" is more economic?

Comment: Could it be there are so many questions on SOF about C# because it is a poor language that needs lots of help to use effectively?  One could draw just about any conclusion from raw data like that.

Comment: Because managed code takes care of everything and let's you concentrate on the business, so it reduces coding time. An application with old C++ that took months to develop now is coded in a few days. Even with new libraries (i.e .NET framework) any newbie can write professional code. Google "thread-safe queue" for example and compare old solutions even with .NET with new "System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue" which is now available out of the box.

Comment: @Amardeep: Even it's a poor language or not, more questions shows more engaged people. I believe in "Collective Wisdom".

Answer (score 0):

For DB's: **SQL** - I think the most important missing part in the list you gave.
For your web dev skills, you may also be interested in: ASP.NET MVC, Ruby on Rails.

Comment: MVC is not a language, but I agree... MVC rocks

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look on the places that hire programmers for a current answer to that.  Obviously, you can look here, on [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/), but there's also craigslist, monster, career builder, rent-a-coder and so-on.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile platforms are seeing the largest growth at the moment, so Objective C/iOS, Java/Android and C#/Windows 7 Mobile are showing higher demand at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do in the future?  Web developer?  System coder?  Databases?  Unless you're 40+ years old I doubt that you've conquered all there is to know about the aforementioned list of languages (c++, java, vb.net , asp.net c#, php, html, css, javascript, coldfusion).  Excluding C++ most of these languages have had massive revamps in the past few years which require constant updating to be on top of.  There's no real point in learning 1000 languages.  It is however, another thing completely to learn the concepts of what can be implemented in languages at different levels.  But, again, that depends on what level you want to be coding at.  If, for some strange reason, you just want to learn new syntaxes - try out Python.  However, if you're actually trying to learn something relevant, figure out what level you're trying to develop at and become a master of the concepts you need to know at that level.  Which language you use to implement the concepts doesn't really matter.